# Item da lista de arquivos selecionados no input não é removido

Tags: javascript, html, css

Galera, uso os códigos do link abaixo para fazer uma listagem de arquivos que selecionei a partir de um input do tipo "file". Até aí, tudo bem. Quando se remove algum item da lista, aparentemente tudo ocorre sem problemas. Maaaaas... Quando é feito o upload dos arquivos para o servidor, o item que foi removido continua sendo enviado.

http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/yrvyf2gn/

Alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

O motivo disso estar acontecendo é que você esta removendo apenas o item do `DOM` que você criou, apenas a linha com o thumbnail e o nome do arquivo, você não esta removendo o arquivo do valor do `<input type="file" />`.

Dei uma pesquisada sobre o assunto e esse valor retornado pela api do html5 é um `FileList` que na verdade não tem nada de lista, é um objeto, e esse objeto é `readonly`.

Fontes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144419/how-do-i-remove-a-file-from-the-filelist
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileList

Comment: Entendo. Mas há alguma maneira de contornar isso nesse modelo que estou usando?

Comment: Eu ja fiz algo do tipo usando angularjs, jquery não. Estou procurando uma solução. Como não foi algo rápido de se achar deixei a resposta rápida sobre o assunto.

Comment: Pior que estou tendo uma certa dor de cabeça com isso e procurando alguma solução. Por via das dúvidas, caso ainda tenha essa opção com o AngularJS, poderia disponibilizar, por obséquio?

Comment: Subo ele aqui outra hora, to fazendo um deploy aqui e esse código quando eu fiz eu e Deus entendia ele, agora só Deus hahaha Vou ter que parar pra ler ele pois é de um projeto do meu antigo trabalho e tem alguns tratamentos nele.

Comment: Kkkkkkk. Tudo bem.